# How can hit a route specified inside the parent component with history.push('somePath_fromParentComp') from its child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is my structure for routes

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    
    <AuthFBContextProvider>
            <LangContextProvider>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <App />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </LangContextProvider>
    </AuthFBContextProvider>
);
```

App.js

```
return (
        <Switch>
          {/* <Route path='/' exact>
            <Redirect to='/en' />
          </Route> */}
          <Route path='/en'>
            <EnglishRouter />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/fr">
            <FrenchRouter/>
          </Route>
          <Route path='*'>
            <NotFound />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
);
```

**EnglishRouter.js** (renders only when path is '/en'), this is my **parent component**

```
<MainNavigation>
        <p>english route</p>
        <Switch>
            <Route path={path} exact>
                <MainPage />  
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/promotions`} exact> -> renders on en/promotions
                <Promotions />
            </Route>
            **<Route path={`${path}/auth`}> -> renders on en/auth
                <AuthPage />
            </Route>**
        </Switch>
    </MainNavigation>)
```

**AuthPage.js** (which renders on 'en/auth') which is **child component**

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/signup`} component={Signup} exact/>
        <Route path={`${path}/login`} component={Login} exact/>
        <Route path={`${path}/forgot-password`} component={ForgotPassword} exact/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Login.js

```
const Login = () => {
    const authFBCtx = useContext(AuthFBContext);
    const { path, url } = useRouteMatch()
    const history = useHistory();

    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
        const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;
        authFBCtx.login(enteredEmail, enteredPassword);
        **history.push('en/promotions')**
      }

    return(...<form onSubmit{submitHandler}><form>)
```

Now the trouble is,

If I do history.push(en/promotion or any other link) after login from Login.js,
it will change to the correct url('en/promotions') but the Promotion.js does not load.

now I could put manually next to other Routes in AuthPage.js to catch the Route which
then loads Promotions.js which does render Promotions while nested.

AuthPage.js updated

```
 <Route path='/en/promotions' component={Promotions} exact/>
 <Route path={`${path}/login`} component={Login} exact/>
 <Route path={`${path}/signup`} component={Signup} exact/>
```

**But the active compoent/path is still happening inside AuthPage.js not from our Parent
component which is EnglishRouter.js**

NavLink of my Navigation is showing the active path/route to be '/en/auth' even after

`history.push('en/promotions')`

[image]

I want history('en/promotions') From inside LoginPage.js to hit its parent route
located in EnglishRouter.js so that the active route on the parent component.

How can I do this??

it seems whatever i do, it is all happening inside my child component...
I dont know if I made myself clear...

Comment: Can you provide all the routing code (router, routes, etc..) for all these components so we can see how they relate? If possible, could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese is the code above enough? i am not familiar with codesandbox but i will try in the meantime, please have a look and i have also tried history(../..) like you explained from another routing post...

Comment: It may. Does the `FrenchRouter` component effectively render the same routes? By this I mean, is the `"/fr/*"` the only thing that differentiate routes and components from `"/en/*"`? And by any chance are you open to using `react-router-dom@6`?

Comment: @DrewReese um... I havent seen a tutorial or video on how to go from v5 to v6 but if that is what will fix the issue, then i will do whatever, it takes but i also do dont want to mess up other routing functions as the app is already built with v5.... I hope it wont lead to more debugging anymore than what i have currently

Comment: @DrewReese yes when i switch into "fr/nested_path", the browswer does render anything on  "en/*".  i console logged this to test between fr/paths and en/paths, when the router is looking at path="/en" it will not look at any other paths or the other path's nested routes...

Comment: This is actually one aspect of RRDv5 (*and to a certain extent even in v6*) that I was never too fond of, that even when using the `match` object to create nested routes/links, or using relative routes/links, that the components still sort of need to be aware of *where* in the routing tree they were being rendered so you could link elsewhere outside the sub-routeTree, i.e. from `"/en/auth*"` to `"/en/promotions*"`. I'll see what I can come up with in RRDv5.

Comment: Is there any issue with using `history.push("/en/promotions")`? See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-hit-a-route-specified-inside-the-parent-component-with-history-pushsom-kb3x4i). I suppose the issue may be that you want to use the same components in the `"/fr"` sub-routes and the login success path for `history.push` would be different? Do you have some language provider depending on which of `EnglishRouter` or `FrenchRouter` is rendered? Is there some app state that holds the current language code?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, i totally agree, when routes are nested, where the url path in the address bar is one thing and where the router is actually LOOKING AT in the tree is another thing which is very confusing and took me a while to figure out the difference... I have seen the match object but need to look into it...

Comment: Oh, when I was referring to the `match` object, that was either the one used in the route props, or the same one returned by the `useRouteMatch` hook that I see you are using (*and what I used in my sandbox code for you*).

Comment: @DrewReese for the language, i am thinking of connecting Firebase's AuthUser's device language to my React's language state in Context API. But currently as you see on my index.js, i am using context api for language which can be seleted on my MainNavigation which is basically RRD's Link to put 'en' and extract it and call context api in my useEffect, i dont know if this make sense... but I also need to start thinking about somehow connecting this with Firebase so that Firebase can take over with the user profile and connect with language context

Comment: @DrewReese I forgot to mention after useEffect (()=>{setLanauge('match.path')}), state language is set to be whatever the lang the user wishes to have and this language state will render different routes (which can be conditionally with JS) this works very well but I need to sync this process up with Firebase which i am using for DB, Auth, Storage and etc.

Comment: @DrewReese for other languages, it will be the same structure and plan to use same components, i am using path='en' as my prototype, if english path works well, i know that i can do the same with other languages (well at least i hope...), let me try to now see what youve written in codesandbox

Comment: I think it'd be better to define a single route where the language code it a dynamic path parameter, e.g. `<Route path="/:lang" component={LanguageRouter} />` and read the `lang` value from the `match.params` or the `useParams` hook. You could still use a `useEffect` hook with that value for the same thing, and then any deeply nested component can link to a route from root so long as they know what the current language is. Does this make sense?

Comment: ive tried again history.push("/en/promotions"), it does not work, so basically our RRD is looking for "/en/promotions" inside AuthPage.js and not App.js. I wish i could do ../en/promotions but it seems like RRD is bend on looking at the current active page which is AuthPage.js. This is really frustrating...

Comment: Feel free to fork the sandbox I created and add in more of your code until it reproduces the issue, then we can take a live look at it.

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew, i restructured my react app on codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-hit-a-route-specified-inside-the-parent-component-with-history-pushsom-forked-trvrr9?file=/src/pages/en/authPage/Login.js

Comment: and it works perfectly fine, i also added styling with NavLink to be able to see the active css class of it and after history.push("/en/promotions") gets triggered from Login.js, react dom is able to move to the parent route... which blows my mind lol and look at the css styling on the NavLink, now the parent route is active.

Comment: Unless I am somehow seriously mistaken with my routes, which i serously doubt, I am starting to suspect that reactv18 that I have is not working with my RRBv5 with the history method which i saw somewhere... i need to now look into this....

Comment: @DrewReese I found the problem, it is that I put Router twice... once in App.js and twice in AuthPage.js if you look above, but you managed somehow to it out when you put the code on codesandbox... god how is this possible lol, i spend so many hours on this...

Comment: @DrewReese can you show me how to go about impententing this ? <Route path="/:lang" component={LanguageRouter} /> I want to have this correctly before i finish off my authentication. I really appreciate for trying...

Comment: I tried this but I feel like it can be more dynamic using params.lang alone with routes in stead of using if logic, this is what I came up with: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-implement-language-router-reactjs-jr430q?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Login.js where I put another Router apart from in App.js

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/signup`} component={Signup} exact/>
        <Route path={`${path}/login`} component={Login} exact/>
        <Route path={`${path}/forgot-password`} component={ForgotPassword} exact/>
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

this is why whenever i used history(/en/promotions), the active path was
not able to look outside of this Router and was looking at the Routes specified
in Login.js...

I spent literally 12 hrs on feel so sorry for myself...

Comment: Ack, and you know what, I even noticed the extraneous router around the auth routes, and *did* remove it in my sandbox, then promptly forgot to mention it. Sorry.

Comment: no problem, youve been a big help, does this look ok for your routing idea? https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-implement-language-router-reactjs-jr430q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Close, was trying to suggest something more like this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-implement-language-router-reactjs-forked-2pnddy?file=/src/router/LanguageRouter.js).

Comment: @DrewReese thank you Drew, i will review the code and get back to you...

Comment: @DrewReese hi drew, so i just review your code and the main benefit is that i dont have to make seperate routers for english, french and etc which results in less coding? I remember you saying something some deep nesting....

Comment: Effectively yes, it's a way to make the code more DRY where possible.

Comment: @DrewReese ok i understand, i do have to be careful as this will mostly work if i keep the same routing/file structure across all languages being used which i did mention that i will keep the same for now...